# Expected undefined to be defined while testing angular controller with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I'm a newbie in testing Angular Apps with Jasmine, and I can't figure out the cause of this problem...

**The controller**

```
programsModule.controller('ticketCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.disableSendBtn = true;
});
```

**And this is the unit test**

```
'use strict';

describe('app', function () {

    // variables
    var $rootScope, $scope, $controller;

    beforeEach(module('supportModule'));

    describe('ticketCtrl', function () {
        beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$controller_) {
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $controller = _$controller_('ticketCtrl', {
                '$scope': $scope
            });
        }));

        it('Should disable send btn', function () {
            expect($scope.disableSendBtn).toEqual(true);
        });

    });    
});
```

And this is the output of the test

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'disableSendBtn' of undefined
```

And if I test if the `$scope` variable is defined or not by

```
it('Should $scope be defined', function () {
    expect($scope).toBeDefined();
});
```

I get this error too

```
Expected undefined to be defined.
```

So what's the problem here?

**HERE is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LeoAref/bn1wxycs/**

---

**Edit**

I used incorrect module here
`beforeEach(module('app'));`

and I fixed that by using the correct module
`beforeEach(module('supportModule'));`

And I got another error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ticketCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/ng/areq?p0=ticketCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
```

Comment: Try `$controller_('ticketCtrl', {
                $scope: $scope
            });` without using the single quotes

Comment: @WayneEllery, thanks but I got the same error...

Comment: You have a typo: $rootScope = \_$controller_;  <-- change that to  \_$rootScope_

Comment: The next problem is that your it() function is not inside the describe() function. So the beforeEach() never runs.

Comment: @SunilD., thanks, I added `it()` inside `describe()`, and I got the same result

Comment: Doesn't make sense , maybe you should make a plunked or at least update this question with your latest code.

Comment: @SunilD., I added the jsFiddle to the question

Comment: I don't see a problem with the fiddle you created. I added Jasmine report to a fork of your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/eitanp461/bn1wxycs/1/

Answer (score 0):

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ticketCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

This error usually is thrown when trying to instantiate controller that is not defined in the module you initialize in the beforeEach function.

The code that is provided seems fine. The only thing that is missing is to check if karma successfully finds your file. Open your karma.conf.js file and make sure that the file where the controller is defined is listed in or picked up with the regex.

Comment: You can do this by setting Karma's `logLevel` property to `config.LOG_DEBUG`.